# Formal application of Pigeonhole principle on voting and candidates

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle, voting-theory

I am reading about the Pigeonhole principle and the following problem under that section:

> A state has $7$ counties. In one year, three candidates run in a
> statewide election. Is it possible that in each county the same number
> of people vote and the candidate who gets the highest number of votes
> does not get the highest number in any county?

My first thought was that the three candidates $c$ are the "boxes" and the votes $v$ are the "balls" according to the Pigeonhole principle.   We have $v \gt rc \implies$ at least one candidate will get at least $r + 1$ votes (generalized version). But then I got stuck how to expand this.

I came up with an example that actually shows that what the question asks is possible:

| County-1 | County-2 | County-3 | County-4 | County-5 | County-6 | County-7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | B | A | C | A | C |
| B | C | B | A | C | B | C |
| B | C | C | B | B | B | B |
| A | A | C | B | B | A | B |

Here we see that $B$ has the most votes even though B is not the most voted in any county. I do not consider a tie as the same as the case of being the most voted person, but in any case it is not that important to my question.

When I checked the solution provided for the problem it actually did the same thing.

Book's solution:

> If we have $100$ people voting we can have $A$ having $40$ votes in
> each county. Candidate $B$ having $50$ votes in three counties and
> $10$ votes in the remaining four counties while the candidate $C$ gets
> $10$ votes in the first three counties, and $50$ in the remaining four
> counties. This means that statewide, the candidate $A$ $280$ votes,
> candidate $B$ gets $190$ votes and candidate $C$ gets $230$ votes.

At this point, I am confused. How is the pigeonhole principle applicable here then if the actual book's solution offers just a counterexample?

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Also I can't recall the syntax to make a proper table in the post

Comment: See arrays in this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top), although I recommend using `\text{County-1}` to avoid having the titles formatted in math mode.

Comment: In addition to MathJax arrays, you can also use Markdown tables: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: Can you tell us where you read about this?

Comment: If `c` is the number of counties (7), what you're actually showing is that one of the counties will have at least r+1 votes totals, which is true, but not helpful, especially since there are an equal number of voters in each county. If `c` is the number of candidates (3), you're showing at least one candidate had r+1 votes, which is also true but not useful. I think you're mixing up counties and candidates.

Comment: I disagree with OP's counterexample. Problem statement: "...the candidate who gets the highest number of votes does not get the highest number in any county...". The highest number of votes in County 1 in the example is $2$, and the winning candidate (B) did get that many votes. I think the problem requires the winning candidate to get strictly beaten in every county. I believe the minimal counterexample exists with $5$ votes per county.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: In the book "A walk through combinatorics" by Bona

Comment: @barrycarter: In the book's solution only the example of the votes for 100 per county is mentioned. So I have no clue how the principle is applicable formally here

Comment: @paw88789: Even so (my thinking in the example is that B was not the major voter in any county), the solution stated in the book is the one with the $100$ voters in the last paragraph. But my question how is the pigeonhole principle actually applied here?

Comment: @awkward: thank you!

Comment: To answer your question, I think the pigeonhole principle is irrelevant here.  Maybe this is meant as a "trick" question. :)

Comment: @antkam: What is the trick?

Comment: haha, i simply meant, they put it in the section about pigeonhole, and then it's NOT about pigeonhole, just to trick (mess with) the reader.